# Why HoloLens Emulator displays a black screen?

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I am struggling to make HoloLens 2 Unity project work on the Emulator.

What I have tried is to build the project using the Build Settings x64, Local Machine.

It worked for the first time, and I tried 3 or 4 different MRTK example scenes or tutorials... and it is a knightmare to make the project run in the emulator.

I tried running with all the combinations of Release, Debug, x86 and x64.

My question is:

Is there a log that shows what is going wrong? (In this specific case, there was no message in the Output log nor Exceptions shown in Visual Studio).

[Hololens 2 Emulator blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uojtn.png)

EDIT: If someone wants to try running the project, please try this link with the whole Unity Project (version 2020.3.21f1): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X7E4CmUb38CxxQbLmOsf4Bc8mjr_YYp6/view?usp=sharing

EDIT 2: I removed some comments about HoloLens Emulator because I was too angry when I wrote it and it was not adding to the discussion.

Comment: UPDATE: After removing some files from the Unity Project, I built again the scene, with only the GLFT model loader example from MRTK, pointing to the Avocado model in StreamingAssets (nothing else than that, check the google drive link above if needed).

Now, differently from the initial attempts, the log shows the following:
Log txt file link in Google Drive - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xaP6DDDNmsjjN8ia92Ypahem8BhfOfli/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide the information about the version number of the HoloLens Emulator and Windows 10 of the PC? And which edition of your Windows 10 you are using? Generally wondering if there's a consistent way to reproduce this.

Comment: Hi, the HoloLens emulator is 10.1.20348.1432.
The Windows 10 Pro version is 21H1, OS Build 19043.1288, Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0. 
I am using a GTX 1050 Ti video card, with 16 GB memmory PC.
Thanks.

Comment: We downloaded and tested the project you provided, but it works as expected, (we are using HoloLens2 emulator10.0.20348.1432). Could you try to deploy the project with the Sideloading feature provided by HoloLens Device Portal? It seems like something go wrong with VS Debugging. For how to do it, please refer to this link:[Installing an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal#installing-an-app).

Comment: For any issue about using HoloLens emulator, this doc will be helpful: [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-hololens-emulator#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

To debug in a deployed version, you need to build the project with these debug settings enabled

[image: unity settings]

And then you will be able to attach unity debugger from Visual studio and analyze logs and also other useful debugger tools.

[image: visual studio debugger]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).